# Set Linq result field equal to a collection

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to set a field from a Linq result to a collection?
for example:

```
    var fileResult = myCollection.GroupBy(x => new { x.FileId, x.SourceFileName })
           .Select(x => new OutputEntity()
           {
            FileId = x.Key.FileId,
            SourceFileName = x.Key.SourceFileName,
            Batches = List<Batch>I want to add a list of Batch objects here,
            ScannedBatchCount = x.Count(y => y.BatchType == "S"),
            });
```

Comment: Tried `Batches = x.ToList()`? Assuming `x` is `Batch` of course.

Comment: What happened when you tried doing it?

Comment: @Jason Can you share a snippet on .NetFiddle?